# What freehub do I need?

Tags: shimano, freehub

The bearings in my freehub are starting to go and I'd like to replace the part. Sadly I have no idea of the part I need to replace it with and cannot find anything specific. My bike is a Merida 140 2016 with a 10 speed shimano rear cassette. The hub specification I can find is limited to "Rear Hub: Bearing Centerlock- 12mm rear" with a slightly better model saying "Rear Hub: Shimano XT 12mm rear"

Searches for 10 speed shimano freewheel don't give me anything that looks like this.

Anyone any ideas what would work?

[image]

Comment: Is there anything written on the freehub itself?

Comment: By the way: Could it be that you didn’t tighten the cassette nut enough? Those grooves look like they were caused by a loose cassette.

Comment: Freehub - hub connections are like derailleur hangers - so many different formats!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the only way to get a certain answer to this is to contact your countries Merida distributor:

https://www.merida-bikes.com/en/p/about-us/distributors-worldwide-139.html